# Does my sentence structure and the vocabulary make sense?

Tags: british-english

> Helpless I screamed in pain, clenching the ground beside me, as my mind thought back to the moment that led me to my unknown fate.

Does this sentence make sense and have good structure?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine, actually a colorful bit of writing imagery.  One thing you might consider is to add a comma here: "Helpless, I screamed in pain..."  This gives the meaning of "I was helpless, and I screamed in pain..."  Another thing you might consider is to use the past perfect here: "...back to the moment that *had* led me to my unknown fate."  But neither of these are required.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically it's fine, but there are some words you will want to reconsider in your next draft.

- *Clench* means to close the hand in a tight ball, or to grip something tightly in the hand. You may *clench* grass or earth or soil, but *the ground*, though  occasionally used to designate soil, is ordinarily the surface of the earth, so to *clench* it sounds rather odd.
- Your *mind* is the instrument with which you think, not a thinker itself, unless you are drawing a subtle metaphysical distinction which seems out of place in this sensational narrative.
- A succession of moments may be said to *lead* to your fate, figuratively, as milestones upon a path (in fact, *all* past moments lead to your fate!); but what I think you are speaking of is not a *moment* but a past *event* which set you on the path to your fate.
- Your fate may have been *unknown* at the moment of that event; but at the time of which you are speaking it seems to be all too sensibly *known*.

I hope you will not take this as a discouraging criticism. If you hope to be taken seriously as a writer you have to train yourself as a reader, so you may catch and correct such details. Eventually it will become second nature and you will edit the approximations which spring to your mind before they reach your fingers.