# When 'but' means 'exception', what if we put 'not'?

Tags: conjunctions

From [StoneyB's answer:](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22812/does-my-sentence-structure-and-the-vocabulary-make-sense)

> You may clench grass or earth or soil, but the ground.

I know this structure and have read this at many places. It's perfectly fine. But then, is this sentence redundant/incorrect/not preferable? In all cases, **why?**

> You may clench grass or earth or soil, but **not** the ground.

Answer (score 4):

You made a mistake. StoneyB's answer was "Clench means to close the hand in a tight ball, or to grip something tightly in the hand. You may clench grass or earth or soil, but the ground, though occasionally used to designate soil, is ordinarily the surface of the earth, so to clench it sounds rather odd."

That's a comma after "ground" not a period. The first sentence you have above makes no sense. The second sentence makes sense. You can say "A but not B" as a sentence by itself. You can't say "A but B" (usually) without a negation or something. In this case, the "or something" is the next clause of the sentence. "But" is a conjunction that should be followed by a clause in most cases. Your second example is okay because "not" is an adverb and it's understood that it's modifying "may clench" from the first clause which carries over as the verb of the second clause.

The exception case you're talking about is like this: "You can do anything you want. Anything but that." or "You can have all but one." In this case, "but" is a preposition with the same meaning as "except."

Comment: Still the question is correct. I like Chinese dishes, but noodles - is absolutely fine. Then the question arises... *...,but not noodles.* is okay? Similarly *I can withstand anything, but heat.* is absolutely correct.

Comment: "I like Chinese dishes, but noodles..." Is only acceptable as an incomplete sentence ("..., but noodles, I don't like so much.") and only conversationally.  It typically wouldn't appear in writing, and if it did I'd expect an ellipsis or other indication that the sentence is incomplete.  In contrast, "I can withstand anything but heat." is a complete sentence.

Comment: "I like any  Chinese dish, but noodles." is acceptable. Your example is an incomplete sentence. In your case, you're using "but" as a preposition but it's replacing "except for" not just "except". Snailplane is right. You'd need to follow it with an ellipse or something.

Comment: Are you sure about the comma in "I like any Chinese dish, but noodles"?

Comment: @digitig, that comma should not be there for just "noodles". You only use commas before conjunctions if the conjunction is joining two independent clauses. For example: "I like any Chinese dish, but noodles are gross."